# Syntax highlight Markdown formulas using LaTeX highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, filetype-markdown, filetype-mathjax

I often write non-trivial mathematical formulas inside Markdown documents, and having them syntax-highlighted would really help.

In Markdown, LaTeX math formulae are denoted:
`$x^2$` and `$$x^2$$`, and are escaped as `\$x\$`and `\$\$x\$\$`.

Markdown math formulas are rendered via MathJax (to match future googlers' keywords).

If I use [vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) to syntax highlight the Markdown, how can I use [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) to syntax highlight only the text inside the formulae?

**Note:** I only want the text inside `$` to be treated differently if the filetype is `markdown` or `foobar` (future proofing against my lack of VimL).

**Bonus:** I'd like the `$` delimiters themselves to use the syntax highlight group `Statement`.

**Hints:**

I think these are along the right path, but I couldn't work out how the solution from them:

- Perhaps [vim-SyntaxRange](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-SyntaxRange) would help. (I couldn't work out how to set it up with the delimiters.)
- vim wikia's [Different syntax highlighting within regions of a file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file)
- [This code](https://stsievert.com/blog/2016/01/06/vim-jekyll-mathjax/):

  ```
  " Block math. Look for "$$[anything]$$"
  syn region math start=/\$\$/ end=/\$\$/
  " Inline math. Look for "$[not $][anything]$"
  syn match math_block '\$[^$].\{-}\$'
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use *vim-Markdown*, but just by skimming over its readme, I found its [syntax extension for LaTeX math](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/master/README.md#latex-math)

> Used as `$x^2$`, `$$x^2$$`, escapable as `\$x\$` and `\$\$x\$\$`.
>
> ```
> let g:vim_markdown_math = 1
> ```

The plugin code uses `:syntax include` of the *tex* syntax, just like you also could do with my [vim-SyntaxRange plugin](http://github.com/inkarkat/vim-SyntaxRange).

Comment: When using `vim-markdown` with `g:vim_markdown_math = 1` I see the formula and fencing `$` as uncoloured. What do you see?

Comment: `drmingdrmer/vim-syntax-markdown` does highlight formulae for me, but is too simplistic, hence the question.

Comment: Note that you didn't address activation only if filetype is `markdown` or `foobar`.

Comment: As I don't use that plugin, I haven't tried anything. The [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin will help you with troubleshooting. As per my answer, this seems to be supported by vim-markdown, and its code looks fine to me, so it's likely a configuration error on your side.

Comment: For the activation: vim-markdown is a _filetype plugin_; it will activate for the `markdown` filetype by default. If you want this for a `foobar` filetype, too, you can either `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.foobar setf markdown` (just including additional patterns to markdown), or `au FileType foobar runtime! ftplugin/markdown.vim ftplugin/markdown_*.vim ftplugin/markdown/*.vim` (inheriting from the markdown filetype). All of this is common Vim filetype stuff, so I didn't include it in my answer.