# Indicate break in code highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am creating a markdown file.  My particular markdown compiler has a MathJax plugin, so I can $$ at will in my .md file.  However, LaTeX syntax is decidedly un-markdown-y, and this practice wreaks havoc on my code highlighter.  Specifically, my markdown highlighter expects certain characters to both begin and end.  So, when I use, for example, an _ character, it breaks syntax highlighting in the entire rest of my document.  Is there some way to tell my vim highlighter "hey, don't worry about this one line, it's beyond your reckoning"?

I've found [this Q](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16376/syntax-highlight-markdown-formulas-using-latex-highlighting), but I don't care about highlighting the LaTex specifically, and also [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/turn-off-markdown-highlighting-for-underscores-in-inline-code), but escaping the underscore changes it's LaTeX-y meaning, so that doesn't work for me.

How to "reset" this sort of beginning-end character code highlighting in Vim?